# How do I sort in ruby/rails on two fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I would like to sort by game_date, and then if the date is the same, sort it by team?  What would be the best way to do this?

```
@teams = @user.teams
@games = @teams.reduce([]) { |aggregate, team| aggregate + team.games}.sort_by(&:game_date)
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The best way would be to have your database do it, but if you want to use Ruby:

```
@games = @data.sort_by {|x| [x.game_date, x.team] }
```

The sorting behaviour of `Array` is to sort by the first member, then the second, then the third, and so on.  Since you want the date as your primary key and the team as the second, an array of those two will sort the way you want.

Comment: The problem is that a user has-many teams and a team has-many games, so I am not sure how to navigate down to the game level, so im not sure how to do this on db level?

Comment: Is there a way to specify direction for each of those keys also?

Comment: @daniel-pittman thanks! Also you can sort by few  keys `@games = @data.sort_by {|x, y| [x.game_date, y.name]}`

Answer (score 28):

```
@teams = @user.teams
@games = @teams.games.order("game_date ASC, team ASC")
```

Comment: @teams is an array or a relation.  How does it have a 'games' method?

Comment: Hey thanks for this response, it solved my issue by using this: @service_history = @vehicle.services.order("closed ASC, date_closed DESC") which dealt with putting nils first, then desc date.

Comment: I think this is better because it will use the SQL order if possible, which is faster than sorting an array and works better with pagination.  Right?

Answer (score 9):

```
@teams = @user.teams 
@games = @teams.games.order(game_date: :asc, team: :asc)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to sort an array containing two different objects w/ a differently named date field, you can do this with an attribute alias method in the model.

**note**: using .sort_by! destructively doesn't work.

## News.rb

```
def release_date
    self.publish_date
end
```

## Controller

```
@grid_elements = @news + @albums
@grid_elements = @grid_elements.sort_by(&:release_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a model which have these two fields

Model.all(:order => 'attribute1, attribute2')

Incase the fields are in multiple tables, you can use joins.

Comment: `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`