# Filter blog posts by YAML data

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I have a blog that has 3 kinds of posts:

- Post Type One
- Post Type Two
- Post Type Three

In the blog archive I have my posts sorted by date.

```
-page_articles.sort_by{|a| a.date }.reverse.each_with_index do |article, i|
    %article{class: article.data.link ? "blog link" : "blog"}
        =dt article.date
        =tag_list article.tags
        =blog_link article
        =article.data.summary
        =link_to 'Read me', article
```

What I want is to sort by data AND sort by a YAML data attribute for the post type. I tried this:

```
-page_articles.sort_by{|a| a.date, |b| b.data.kind.post-type-one}.reverse.each_with_index do |article, i|
    %article{class: article.data.link ? "blog link" : "blog"}
        =dt article.date
        =tag_list article.tags
        =blog_link article
        =article.data.summary
        =link_to 'Read me', article
```

But that didn't work. I was wondering what the correct syntax would be to get something like this working.

For reference the post YAMl would look like this:

```
---
kind: post-type-one
---
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort in ruby/rails on two fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143371/how-do-i-sort-in-ruby-rails-on-two-fields)

Comment: I think [this is the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143381/1270789)? `sort_by{|a| a.date, a.data.kind.post-type-one}`